# mockito method when passing an object

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock a DAO method in Spring/Hibernate which takes an object and returns an object.

```
Mockito.when(mockedDao.findByProperty(c)).thenReturn(state);
```

`c` object has key-value pairs like "name", "ben". `state` object would have the employment status.

But when I run the test it returns null. I think its because the `criteria` parameter which I am passing in unit test is not exactly the same all though they are equal. How do I work around this issue? Criteria here is an object with key-values not related to the hibernate criteria...

here is "service.getELementByName":

```
    @Override
@Transactional
public State getElementByName(Object value) {
    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    c.property = "state_name";
    c.value = (String) value;
    State result = (State) stateDAO.findByProperty(c);
    return result;
}
```

please suggest!
Thanks

---

edit
code looks something like this

```
private State state;

@Mock
private StateDAO mockedDao;
@InjectMocks
private StateServiceImpl service;

@Before
public void init() {
    // mockedDao = mock(StateDAO.class);
    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    c.property = "state_name";
    c.value = (String) "Virginia";
    state = new State();
    state.setId(20);
    state.setIntPtLat(37.5222512);
    state.setIntPtLon(-78.6681938);
    state.setStateName("Virginia");
    Mockito.when(mockedDao.findByProperty(eq(c))).thenReturn(state);
    // service = new StateServiceImpl<State>();
}

@Test
public void testFindByProperty() {

    state = new State();
    state.setId(20);
    state.setIntPtLat(37.5222512);
    state.setIntPtLon(-78.6681938);
    state.setStateName("Virginia");

    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    c.property = "state_name";
    c.value = (String) "Virginia";
    Mockito.when(mockedDao.findByProperty(eq(c))).thenReturn(state);
    service.getElementByName("Virginia");
    State result = (State) service.getElementByName("Tes");
    assertEquals(state, result);
}
```

Comment: More code required.  What does a "contact" object look like?  Also, you should review your previous questions and accept some answers if you can.

Comment: More code would definitely be helpful!

Comment: its criteria...i updated the code

Comment: @user1827614 Can add your `Criteria` object to the question? (I'm assuming that it can't be `org.hibernate.Criteria`)

Comment: can you post the code of "service.getElementByName"? Does Criteria class implement equals method? How is Criteria instance instantiated in getElementByName method?

Comment: here is "service.getELementByName":

Comment: You don't need to cast a String literal into a String

Comment: yea...I was trying many things..

Comment: You need to implement equals method in your Criteria class. Criteria instance in test is not equal to Criteria instance in getElementByName method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling Mockito.initMocks(this) anywhere? If not, that may be your problem.

Comment: You are right adding this ..MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); and Mockito.when(mockedDao.findByProperty(any(Criteria.class))).thenReturn(state); fixed the issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

If you need to add behaviour based on that specific instance of `Criteria` being passed to `findByProperty` then you need to get to the bottom of why Mockito doesn't think it's the same - until more code is posted we can't help!

However, if that's not the case and any instance will do, then you can use an argument matcher to relax things a bit, e.g.:

```
Mockito.when(mockedDao.findByProperty(any(Criteria.class))).thenReturn(state);
```

Like I said, it depends on what you're testing though.

I hope that helps.